# How to trigger the failed build using Restart from stage without using UI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to trigger the previously failed build using its build number and Failed stage name in declarative pipeline without using UI

**Say for Ex:**

- Build #1 Failed at Deploy stage
- I don't want to build or test the Build #1 again
- I catch the failed stage details using `${env.FAILED_STAGE}`
- Trigger build #2 as Build #1 as input parameter and the failed stage value
- Here is the counterpart, I am not sure how to use Restart from stage option in Jenkins file

Could someone help me on this